# Links lead to 404 if index.php is not manually input

Tags: php, html

I have a web server hosted on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine with Apache and PHP installed and updated, the server is accessible from a domain ***www.example.com/user1*** where under ***user1*** my pages are located. The problem is that, if I click on any link if I have not manually written index.php in address field, the **/user1** part is dropped - instead of **www.example.com/user1/example.php** browser tries to open **www.example.com/example.php** which leads to a 404 error. Same happens if PHP_SELF is called.

Appreciating every feedback, as I can't find solution for this simple problem.

EDIT: Added the index.php content as it was asked.

```
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Sample menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample menu with sections</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
   <li> <a href="sample1.php">Show the sample1 page</a>
   <li> <a href="sample2.php">Show the sample2 page</a>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
   <li> <a href="sample3.php">Show the sample3 page</a>
   <li> <a href="sample4.php">Show the sample4 page</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you kindly show us the contents of `index.php`?

Comment: Edited the main post to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check wether the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) directive is set correctly in your Apache configuration file like follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Comment: I checked the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf and it included this line. Should it be defined somewhere else (like apache2.conf)?

Comment: @AndrisŠilinis You might want to try as follows: `DirectoryIndex user1/index.php user1/index.html` etc. You can find the config file when pressing the config button at your Apache overview. Select Apache (httpd.conf) there. It's a text file, which you can edit. Search for DirectoryIndex.

Comment: I tried setting the DirectoryIndex as You suggested but with no success. Only change was upon trying to open www.example.com/user1 without index.php, I was displayed the 403 error. With index.php, I was displayed my page but upon calling a PHP_SELF, the user1 part was dropped. Is there any way for apache telling, that the every link must start with www.example.com/user as for now I think it uses only the top level www.example.com?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could make a php file at the top layer that should be loaded when you go to www.example.com as meant to be done with DirectoryIndex. Simply put a `header("www.example.com/user1")` in there. That might fix it. Otherwise I'm bot sure how to deal with this problem.